# Why my dconf-editor has fewer options in Elementary OS Luna than supposed to?

Tags: linux, configuration, elementary-os

I am giving Elementary OS a try but trying to configure it a bit I see lesser options than supposed in dconf-editor. Following [this](http://iblogipple.blogspot.fr/2013/02/how-to-change-elementary-os-luna-font.html) source, they should look like this:

[image]

Mine look like this:

[image]

So, I can neither follow the instructions from [here](http://helpdeskgeek.com/linux-tips/unlock-the-desktop-and-panel-in-elementary-os/).

Why is that?

Is this related to the latest release? A remedy?

Comment: @terdon - there is no 'nautilus' entry in the latest elementary os config editor, that is why i cannot folow the steps. i have posted images with **a lot** of entries which are missing in my system. most of what i see in the images simply is not there anymore. the file manager is not (called) nautilus anymore. what i want is a lot: increase fonts, [see invisible items](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/91294/32012), change themes, generally customizing

Comment: @terdon: pantheon is the file manager. nor pantheon or nautilus are present in my dconfig-editor

Comment: Sorry, can't help. The ElementaryOS guys have a very active irc channel with a [nice web interface](http://elementaryos.org/support/live), if this is a recent thing you might have more luck there. If you do find a solution (and no one answers here) please consider coming back and posting an answer, it will be much appreciated.

Comment: @terdon - i will surely post answers to all my questions if possible. but i am not familiar with irc, cannot see an issue discussed under a certain page etc just hundred of users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a relevant [question](http://elementaryos.org/answers/does-it-possible-to-enable-desktop-icons) on the Elementary OS help pages, one of their moderators said that the current version cannot draw the Desktop and that the [suggested workaround](http://www.elementaryupdate.com/2013/03/enable-desktop-icons-in-elementary-luna.html) is to install `nautilus` and then activate the Desktop through the `dconf-editor`  pretty much as you have attempted to do.

I presume that installing `nautilus` will make the relevant entry appear in `dconf-editor`. They have a nice howto [here](http://web.archive.org/liveweb/http://www.elementaryupdate.com/2013/03/enable-desktop-icons-in-elementary-luna.html).

Comment: thank you. i have stumbled into that answer myself, and i take your answer as a confirmation that this is the only way. i find nevertheless the absence of the default file manager in dconf very odd - a clue for the immature stage of this os, which i still like (somewhat less, is true). i trust this will change for the better. also, as i was trying to configure trough dconf-editor - now i know this is not altogether necessary: there is also 'elementary tweaks' - as i learned from [here](http://www.elementaryupdate.com/2013/08/top-things-to-do-after-installing-luna.html)