# How to see invisible items in Elementary OS Luna?

Tags: nautilus, elementary-os

Nautilus is not the file manager anymore in Elementary OS Luna - or it has change name to Pantheon-files. [Cannot find its settings](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/91288/32012).

How to see invisible items?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>. I found this on the following page, titled: [elementaryupdate](http://www.elementaryupdate.com/2013/05/nitrux-icons-in-elementary-luna.html).

*excerpt*

> INSTALL
>
> To install, download the following file, extract it, and move it to
>   ~/.icons. The folder, .icons, is a hidden folder inside of your home
>   directory. You can show hidden folders by pressing CTRL+H inside of
>   the Files application.